# Log4Net - Process Lock on Files

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

We're using Log4Net with a FileAppender to log errors during a process. As the process is finishing, we want to email the log file but we can't do that as it Log4Net still has a lock on the file and we get a message that the file is in use by another process. Any ideas?

We're using a config like this:

```xml
  <appender name="WarnFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="d:\for-review-log.txt" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="WARN" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    <appendToFile  value="false"></appendToFile>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume log is from some kind of service, so the log will be locked until service is running.

You probably want to use shared lock while reading the file for sending.

Or you can copy the file and send the copy.

Comment: Hi Alex, the log is from a console app process and this will lock the file. Im already using the FileAppender.MinimalLock setting for the appender. Copying the file could be an option ...

Comment: @Steve Ward - Do you access to the code of the application that sends log? If so, you might want to make changes in that one. It should not count that file is not used right now, so it could read file using shared lock or do the file copy.

Answer (score -1):

ive got the same problem. Olso a flush doesn't work and when i try to use the SMTPmailAppender that olso doesn't seem to work somehow. but when i use my own created class to send email it works, only he doesn't add the attachment(logfile)

Comment: Why not focus on the one thing that you say works, than make it appear as if you don't have an answer here ? It's about marketing your answer (the positive), versus seeming like you are stumped.